# useRoute in composible vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I have a file store/service.js and I want use router.

I make this:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const router = useRoute();
function exceptionHandler(error) {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    router.push('/user/login');
  } else if (error.response.status === 404) {
    throw new Error(error.response.data.Message || error.message);
  } else {
    router.push('/error');
  }
}
```

but received a error *undefined* in *router* use.

note: this is not inside setup tag, this is a js external file

Comment: Just import router instance directly if you're unable to guarantee this to be executed in setup

Answer (score 2):

useRoute() can only be used inside setup  so try to write your function as a composable like this

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export function useExceptionHandler(){

const router = useRoute();

function exceptionHandler(error) {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    router.push('/user/login');
  } else if (error.response.status === 404) {
    throw new Error(error.response.data.Message || error.message);
  } else {
    router.push('/error');
  }
}
    return {
        exceptionHandler,
    }
}
```

and you can use it like this on your component

```js
<script setup>

const { exceptionHandler } = useExceptionHandler();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is not quite possible, you can only use `useRoute` in setup, because that's a hook. What you can do, however, is to import the router from its file into your script and use it.